# An application loader with threads

Tags: java, swing, awt, splash-screen

I'm currently developing a basic java project and with my application initial starting time quite slow.

I came across the idea to do an application loader - like eclipse loader - which load the application giving a nice effect, after some searching I didn't find a thing about it, but I have a wide idea about using a thread to load it but I'm quite lost.

So how it's done? And is there a way better than threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the official documentation of The Java Tutorials - [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).